# Association Structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I currently have associations like this:

Category belongs_to User
User has_many Categories

A User can create a category

However, The problem I am having is how do I associate Users to their `liked` categories. A User can `like` a Category even if it is created by another User.

I am looking into creating another Model with

user_id and category_id

How do I go about creating the Model and how would the relationship be? A Category should still `belongs_to` to a `User` but a User can `like` a `Category`.

Comment: It's more or less the same problem as users/friends in a social network, have a look here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

Comment: But the categories or the users don't need to be associated with itself. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirements there should be two relationships.

```
1. User has_many :categories  and 
   Category belongs_to :user
2. User habtm :favorite_cats, :class_name => 'Category'  and 
   Category habtm :liked_by_users, :class_name => 'User'
```